# Python - blank range defaulting to preset range

Tags: python, random, default, dice

here is my code so far:

```
import random

normal_dice=6

def roll(sides):
    for i in range(sides == ""):
        return random.randint(1,normal_dice)
    for i in range(1,int(sides)):
        return random.randint(1,int(sides))
    for i in range(int(sides),1):
        print("None")
```

everything works except when user input is blank, I get the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#29>", line 1, in <module>
    roll()
TypeError: roll() missing 1 required positional argument: 'sides'
```

What I want is for when user input is blank, a random number between 1 and 6 is generated

any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: If user input is blank, and you call `roll(the_user_input)`, you won't get this error. The problem is that, somewhere, you're calling `roll()`, without passing anything at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't shown us the code that calls `roll`, which is where the problem is.

However, if you want to make it so that `roll` can be called without any argument at all, you can do that by using a default parameter value:

```
def roll(sides='6'):
```

If the default is something more complicated (e.g., instead of "use the usual rule, with 6 sides" it's "use a different rule"), you just set the default value to something that isn't valid. Either `None`:

```
def roll(sides=None):
    if sides is None:
        return special_rule()
```

… or, if `None` is a valid argument, a custom sentinel object:

```
_sentinel = object()
def roll(sides=_sentinel):
    if sides is _sentinel:
        return special_rule()
```

---

As a side note, your code isn't doing the right thing for almost any input. Let's step through it:

```
for i in range(sides == ""):
    return random.randint(1,normal_dice)
```

This is right, but in a very convoluted way. If `sides == ""`, it will count from 0 to 1, and return a number from 1 to 6 the first time through the loop. Otherwise, it will count from 0 to 0, meaning we skip over the whole loop.

```
for i in range(1,int(sides)):
    return random.randint(1,int(sides))
```

Here, if `sides` is any number greater than 1, like `"8"`, you will count from 1 to 8, and return `randint(1, 1)` the first time through, so it'll always return 1 and never get to the rest of the loop. If it's 1 or less, it will skip over the loop.

```
for i in range(int(sides),1):
    print("None")
```

And this code will print out the string `None` multiple times, which can't be very useful, before finally falling off the end of the function and returning `None`.

I think what you wanted is something like this:

```
def roll(sides='6'):
    sides = int(sides)
    if sides > 1:
        return random.randint(1, sides)
    else:
        raise ValueError("Can't roll a {}-sided die".format(sides))
```

If you took out the `if` check and just did a `return random.randint(1, sides)`, passing a number smaller than 1 would raise an exception like `ValueError: empty range for randrange() (1, 0, 0)`. That's a little hard for a user to understand. And you were (I think) explicitly checking for that case in the original version. So, I put in a simpler explicit check, which gives you a nicer error message: `ValueError: can't roll a 0-sided die`.

Comment: I'm not really sure I understand.                                      
    import random  
    def roll(sides='6'):  
        if sides >= 1:  
            return random.randint(1,int(sides))  
        else:  
            print("None")

Comment: @user2913576: What do you not understand about it? I can try to add some explanation, but it would help to know which part confuses you…

Comment: I'm sorry I'm new to this website. even when I write def roll(sides='6') it still returns the NameError. also the code that calls roll could be roll() or roll(8)